# C# GC. Do calls to VirtualAlloc and VirtualFree Win32 functions cause page swap?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

MSDN says that GC calls the Win32 VirtualAlloc function to reserve segment of memory and calls the Win32 VirtualFree to release segments back to the operating system.

Does that mean **each time a segment allocated/released there is a Page Fault generated** (soft or hard - depends on the memory availability).

Is that correct interpretation?

Comment: *All* Windows programs use VirtualAlloc/Free.  Page faults don't happen until the memory is accessed.

Comment: could you please explain - if a program calls VirtualAlloc AND access the allocated memory immediately afterwards - will it ALWAYS generate page fault?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Individual pages within a block allocated by `VirtualAlloc` are committed via soft page faults. There's no reason for a call to `VirtualFree` to cause page faults, however, since it's just bookkeeping.

That's not to say that GC allocations always cause page faults: in the absence of a memory leak, the GC will collect garbage, and re-use the part of the heap belonging to that garbabge, before it requests more memory from the OS.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the " not to say that GC allocations always cause page faults". My question was specific to GC allocating a segment. Not allocation of memory for a new object by .NET.... Are you saying that GC segment allocation is not always cause a page fault?

Comment: Yes, I expect GC segment allocation to always cause page faults. That is because I expect all segment allocations to cause page faults, whether they're in code that uses a GC, or unmanaged code. Note that these will be soft page faults, which are mostly harmless.

Answer (score 1):

A page fault is a trap to the software raised by the hardware when a program accesses a page that is mapped in the virtual address space, but not loaded in physical memory

So the short answer is NO.